# How to feed two arrays into apply

Tags: r

I have two 3-D arrays, and I want to calculate some statistics on them. As long as I am working with only one variable, I know how to do it. For example, to calculate the mean over the first dimension, I use the following:

```
obs<-array(1:8,c(2,2,2));
mod<-array(9:2,c(2,2,2));

meanObs <- apply(obs,c(2,3),mean)    # mean of observation
meanMod <- apply(mod,c(2,3),mean)   # mean od model simulation/forecast
```

However, I do not know how to feed two sliced array into apply. For example, I am trying to calculate the correlation coefficient over the first dimension. I can do it with the following loop functions:

```
pearsonCor<-matrix(, nrow = dim(obs)[2], ncol = dim(obs)[3])
for (i in 1:dim(obs)[2]){
  for (j in 1:dim(obs)[3]){
  pearsonCor[i,j]<-tryCatch(suppressWarnings(cor(obs[,i,j], mod[,i,j], method = "pearson")),
                   error=function(cond) {return(NA)})
  }
}
```

result:

```
  > pearsonCor
       [,1] [,2]
 [1,]   -1   -1
 [2,]   -1   -1
```

But I want to learn how to deal with this situation with apply.Any help would be very much appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: Looks like it might be a job for `mapply()`

Comment: Do you know how to rephrase this into mapply?

Comment: Just by looking at it, I might give `f <- function(i, j) cor(obs[, i, j], mod[, i, j], method = "pearson"); mapply(f, 1:dim(obs)[2], 1:dim(obs)[3])` a shot.  But it would be best if you could create a small reproducible example with desired result

Comment: I edited the question so you can reproduce some results. If I use mapply as you suggested, it will return only 2 values. As it passes first 1 and 1, and then 2 and 2. But what I want is all different combinations of i and j.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `expand.grid` to get the index combination as in your nested `for` loop.  Then `apply` over the `data.frame` of indices.

```
pearsonCor[] <- apply(expand.grid(1:dim(obs)[2], 1:dim(obs)[3]), 1, function(x)
    cor(obs[,x[[1]], x[[2]]], mod[,x[[1]], x[[2]]]))
```

This will actually loop more quickly over the first variable (corresponding to `i` in the loops), so the indices would need to be reversed to have the matrix in the ordering of your question.

Comment: Or you could use `outer` and `Vectorize`

Comment: $nongkrong 's solution is good, I should take an extra step converting the vector at the end to the matrix I want. Thanks,

Comment: if I substitute apply with plyr::aaply, then the transformation to a matrix will be handled automatically. Just for clarification.